# How to add parameters in module class in pytorch custom model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I tried to find the answer but I can't.

I make a custom deep learning model using pytorch. For example,

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.nn_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        self.layer = nn.Linear(2,3).double()
        torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.layer.weight)

        self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(3))

        self.nn_layers.append(self.layer)

    def forward(self, x):
        activation = torch.tanh
        output = activation(self.layer(x)) + self.bias

        return output
```

If I print

```
model = Net()
print(list(model.parameters()))
```

it does not contains model.bias, so 
optimizer = optimizer.Adam(model.parameters()) does not update model.bias.
How can I go through this?
Thanks!

Comment: If you are subclassing module see the solution posted here. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-make-a-tensor-part-of-model-parameters/51037/6. Test with print(list(model.parameters())).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to [register](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.register_parameter) your parameters:

```py
self.register_parameter(name='bias', param=torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(3)))
```

---

**Update:**
In more recent versions of PyTorch, you no longer need to explicitly `register_parameter`, it's enough to set a member of your `nn.Module` with `nn.Parameter` to "notify" pytorch that this variable should be treated as a trainable parameter:

```py
self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(3))
```

Please note that is you want to have more complex data structures of parameters (e.g., lists, etc.) you should use dedicated containers like [`torch.nn.ParameterList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.ParameterList.html) or [`torch.nn.ParameterDict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.nn.ParameterDict.html).

Comment: Thank you! I think
```
self.register_parameter(name='bias', param=torch.nn.Parameter(self.bias))
```
does not work. Is there a way to get rid of 'name' part? I think this will be troublesome when save and load the model.

Comment: @CSH by using `name='bias'` when registering the parameter you implicitly creates `self.bias` to be used in your `Net` class. you do _not_ need to explicitly assign `self.bias` for it to exist.

Comment: OMG. What a convenient function! Thank you for your helps!

Comment: It should be `torch.nn.parameter.Parameter` now.