# Best way to define a scalar using nn.Parameter in Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

In my CNN at some stage I want to multiply a feature map with some scalar which should be learnt by the network. Which of the following is the best way to do it or all are same? The scalar has to be initialised to 5.

```
# Method 1
def __init__(self):
    super(..., self).__init__()
    ...
    ...
    alpha = nn.Parameter(5)
    ...

def forward(self, x):
    ...
    x = x * alpha
    return x
```

```
# Method 2
def __init__(self):
    super(..., self).__init__()
    ...
    ...
    alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(5))
    ...

def forward(self, x):
    ...
    x = x * alpha
    return x
```

```
# Method 3
def __init__(self):
    super(..., self).__init__()
    ...
    ...
    alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1)*5)
    ...

def forward(self, x):
    ...
    x = x * alpha
    return x
```

If all are same I would prefer Method 1 and let CNN learn the appropriate multiplier `alpha` for the feature map `x`. I hope in all cases alpha will be a float32 tensor initialised to 5. I am using PyTorch 1.3.1

Yours sincerely,

Mohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third option will work since the parameter constructor needs a float. Parameters are updated with the optimizer, so they need to have gradients, apart from buffers.

Buffers are managed by yourself, not with the optimizer.

You may play with this experimental code.

```
BS=2
class M(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(BS, 2))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(BS))
        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(5.))

    def forward(self, x):
        return x @ self.weights + self.bias

m=M()
m.parameters()
list(m.parameters())
```

Out:

```
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[-0.5627,  2.3067],
         [ 1.3821, -0.1893]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
 tensor([0., 0.], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
 tensor(5., requires_grad=True)]
```

Here I directly set the value `5.` to the parameter alpha, and I added a few more parameters for fun.

You could [also do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234238/how-to-add-parameters-in-module-class-in-pytorch-custom-model) as explained by Shai:

```
self.register_parameter(name='alpha', param=torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(5.)))
```

You may asked why we have [`nn.Module.register_parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Flatten.html#torch.nn.Flatten.register_parameter), why don't we just use the `nn.Parameter()` approach?

`nn.Module.register_parameter` takes the `name` and tensor and first checks if the `name` is in the dictionary of the module. While `nn.Parameter()` doesn't have such a check.

Comment: From your experimental code it appears that Method 2 should also work just that `5` has to be replaced with `5.`. Is this correct? I have ruled out Method 1. And thankyou for pointing out `register_buffer`. But even if i just use `nn.Parameter`, should the code still work?

Comment: @Shai pointed at register_buffer. ;) and yes, `nn.Parameter()` will work the same way as `register_parameter`. If you alter your example to 5. you have exactly my example ;)