# The learnable parameter problem of the conv2d layer in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Recently I tried to use custom conv2d convolutional layer parameters, the current setting is:

```
        kernel = [np.array([[0., 0., 0.], [0., -1., 0.], [0., 1., 0.]]),
                  np.array([[0., 0., 0.], [0., -1., 1.], [0., 0., 0.]]),
                  np.array([[0., 0., 0.], [0., -1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]])]
        self.weights = []
        for kernel_filter in kernel:
            kernel_filter = torch.FloatTensor(kernel_filter).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)  # (1, 1, 3, 3)
            kernel_filter = np.repeat(kernel_filter, self.channels, axis=0)
            self.weights.append(nn.Parameter(data=kernel_filter, requires_grad=True)) 
...
        for weight in self.weights:
            image_filtered = F.conv2d(x, weight, stride=[1, 1], padding=1, groups=self.channels)
```

After training several times, I checked the parameter values and found that there is no change. May I ask why this is, or what is wrong with my understanding here.

Comment: Does your optimizer include these parameter groups?

Comment: yes, i use 'self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.model.parameters()), lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.999))' to optimize the trainable parameters. Is there something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Print out all of the model parameters and ensure that they are registered, I suspect they are not. See here: [How to add parameters in module class in pytorch custom model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234238/how-to-add-parameters-in-module-class-in-pytorch-custom-model).  In short, just because `self.weights` is an attribute of the model class doesn't mean the model recognizes it as a learnable parameter. To indicate this to the model, you call `self.register_parameter`.

(As such, this question contains the same info as the linked question so perhaps should be closed, though I could perhaps see this being a useful avenue for people less familiar with terminology to reach the info.)

Comment: I found the answer from the link you sent, using `self.register_parameter(name=f"kernel_filter{i}", param=nn.Parameter(data=kernel_filter, requires_grad=True))`, I can see these parameters from the model. Thank you very much! But I don’t know how to close the question, will it close automatically?

Comment: I trained the model once and then looked at the parameter values and they did not change. This is a binary classification model. Is there any error?

Comment: The forward function is:   `    def forward(self, x):
        residuals = []
        for weight in self.weights:
            image_filtered = F.conv2d(x, weight, stride=[1, 1], padding=1, groups=self.channels)
            residuals.append(image_filtered)
        return torch.cat(residuals, dim=1)`